# XGBOOST/lLightgbm over-fitting despite no indication in cross-validation test scores?

Tags: cross-validation, xgboost, lightgbm

We aim to identify predictors that may influence the risk of a relatively rare outcome.

- We are using a semi-large clinical dataset, with data on nearly 200,000 patients.
- The outcome of interest is binary (i.e. yes/no), and quite rare (~ 5% of the patients).
- We have a large set of nearly 1,200 mostly dichotomized possible predictors.

Our objective is not to create a prediction model, but rather to use the boosted trees algorithm as a tool for variable selection and for examining high-order interactions (i.e. to identify which variables, or combinations of variables, that may have some influence on the outcome), so we can target these predictors more specifically in subsequent studies. Given the paucity of etiological information on the outcome, it is somewhat possible that none of the possible predictors we are considering have any influence on the risk of developing the condition, so if we were aiming to develop a prediction model it would have likely been a rather bad one. For this work, we use the R implementation of XGBoost/lightgbm.

We have been having difficulties tuning the models. Specifically when running cross validation to choose the optimal number of iterations (nrounds), the CV test score continues to improve even at very high values (for example, see figure below for nrounds=600,000 from xgboost). This is observed even when increasing the learning rate (eta), or when adding some regularization parameters (e.g. max_delta_step, lamda, alpha, gamma, even at high values for these).

As expected, the CV test score is always lower than the train score, but continuous to improve without ever showing a clear sign of over fitting. This is true regardless of the evaluation metrics that is used (example below is for logloss, but the same is observed for auc/aucpr/error rate, etc.).  Relatedly, the same phenomenon is also observed when using a grid search to find the optimal value of tree depth (max_depth). CV test scores continue to improve regardless of the number of iterations, even at depth values exceeding 100, without showing any sign of over fitting.

Note that owing to the rare outcome, we use a stratified CV approach. Moreover, the same is observed when a train/test split is used instead of CV.

Are there situations in which over fitting happens despite continuous improvements in the CV-test (or test split) scores? If so, why is that and how would one choose the optimal values for the hyper parameters?

Relatedly, again, the idea is not to create a prediction model (since it would be a rather bad one, owing that we don’t know much about the outcome), but to look for a signal in the data that may help identify a set of predictors for further exploration. If boosted trees is not the optimal method for this, are there others to come to mind? Again, part of the reason we chose to use boosted trees was to enable the identification of higher (i.e. more than 2) order interactions, which cannot be easily assessed using more conventional methods (including lasso/elastic net, etc.).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

In the absence of some code and representative data it is not easy to make other than general suggestions.

Your descriptive statistics step may give some pointers to a starting model.

What does existing theory (if it exists!) suggest about the cause of the medical condition?

Is there a male/female difference or old/young age difference that could help get your foot in the door?

Your medical data has similarities to the fraud detection problem where one is trying to predict rare events usually much rarer than your cases.
It may pay you to check out the use of xgboost/lightgbm in the fraud detection literature.